# How to create multi ring donut pie chart?

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I need to create a multi ring donut pie chart.

I need space between those rings for good visual feel like the below image.

[image]

Is there anyway to achieve this requirement using `highcharts` ? We are using `4.0.1` version

Thanks in advance

Comment: Play around with [`innerSize`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.innerSize) and [`size`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using solidgauge and innerRadius / outerRadius params.

```
series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        innerRadius:'60%',
        outerRadius: '70%',
        data: [80]
    },{
        name: 'Speed',
        innerRadius:'80%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        data: [120]
    }]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3m1L29oh/1/

Comment: Is it possible to add space between the rings ?

Comment: In that case you need to develop angular gauge and then use plodBands, like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/zysvcf3v/1/